# I am searching for a metric space in which every Cauchy sequence is stationary.

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am searching for an example of a metric space in which every Cauchy sequence is stationary, means that there exists some $N$ such that for all $n>N$: $a_n = a_N$.
Is there a simple example for this?

Comment: The discrete metric where all distances are equal to one, except the distance from a point to itself which is zero.

Comment: Ok, that's not what I had in mind. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: Okay then how about $\Bbb N$ with the usual metric?

Comment: What'd you have in mind?  I'm not sure if examples can get any simpler.

Comment: The only way it's going to happen is if points are open and so you need a discrete space like $\Bbb N$ or the discrete metric.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does this mean, that $\mathbb{N}$ with the metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ is a complete metric space?

Comment: Yes, it is complete because all Cauchy sequences converge.  It's not very interesting as a complete space but it is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that the metric space is discrete (i.e. for each $x \in X$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $d(x,y) > \epsilon$ for all $y \ne x$) and complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helps understanding the concept.